# How to create a system-wide alias to a shared directory

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux and I need to create a system-wide alias that takes an user to their departmental shared data directory. Users could have different departmental folder. Does somebody have any clue?

Comment: Wow, how do you decide that a question is about general computing? Do you follow any manual or rules about that?. Please, let me know. I would not want to bother you

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a *symbolic link*. Use the ln command.

For a soft link:

```
ln -s <source path> <alias>
```

Comment: well, it should be an system-wide alias and the path could be different for each user

Comment: so what is your question? script it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [softlink or symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) .

```
ln -s "path to the source directory"  "name of the alias"
```

Comment: well, it should be an system-wide alias and the path could be different for each user